# Convert pyspark string to date format

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date pyspark dataframe with a string column in the format of `MM-dd-yyyy` and I am attempting to convert this into a date column.

I tried:

```
df.select(to_date(df.STRING_COLUMN).alias('new_date')).show()
```

And I get a string of nulls. Can anyone help?

Comment: Unless you're using one of the TimeSeriesRDD addons (see the Spark 2016 conference for some discussion, there are two I know of but both are still in development), there aren't a lot of great tools for time series.  Accordingly, I've found there's rarely a reason to bother converting strings to datetime objects, if your goal is verious types of `groupBy` or resampling operations.  Just perform them on the string columns.

Comment: The analysis will be done using little to no ```groupBy``` but rather longitudinal studies of medical records. Therefore being able to manipulate the date is important

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I get null results from date\_format() PySpark function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094413/why-i-get-null-results-from-date-format-pyspark-function)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

**Update** (1/10/2018):

For Spark 2.2+ the best way to do this is probably using the [`to_date`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) or [`to_timestamp`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) functions, which both support the `format` argument. From the docs:

```python
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])
>>> df.select(to_timestamp(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('dt')).collect()
[Row(dt=datetime.datetime(1997, 2, 28, 10, 30))]
```

**Original Answer** (for Spark < 2.2)

It is possible (preferrable?) to do this without a udf:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, from_unixtime

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("11/25/1991",), ("11/24/1991",), ("11/30/1991",)], 
    ['date_str']
)

df2 = df.select(
    'date_str', 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date_str', 'MM/dd/yyy')).alias('date')
)

print(df2)
#DataFrame[date_str: string, date: timestamp]

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+----------+-------------------+
#|date_str  |date               |
#+----------+-------------------+
#|11/25/1991|1991-11-25 00:00:00|
#|11/24/1991|1991-11-24 00:00:00|
#|11/30/1991|1991-11-30 00:00:00|
#+----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using an udf for this will destroy your performance.

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp

Comment: Note that you can find a java date format reference here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Also note that `to_date()` with the format argument is spark 2.2+.  `to_date` existed before 2.2, but the format option did not exist

Comment: TL;DR: `df = df.withColumn("ResultColumn", to_timestamp(col("OriginalDateCol"), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))`

Answer (score 50):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType



# Creation of a dummy dataframe:
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("11/25/1991","11/24/1991","11/30/1991"), 
                            ("11/25/1391","11/24/1992","11/30/1992")], schema=['first', 'second', 'third'])

# Setting an user define function:
# This function converts the string cell into a date:
func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'), DateType())

df = df1.withColumn('test', func(col('first')))

df.show()

df.printSchema()
```

Here is the output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|     first|    second|     third|      test|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|11/25/1991|11/24/1991|11/30/1991|1991-01-25|
|11/25/1391|11/24/1992|11/30/1992|1391-01-17|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+

root
 |-- first: string (nullable = true)
 |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |-- third: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: date (nullable = true)
```

Comment: A `udf` shouldn't be necessary here, but the built ins for handling this are atrocious.  This is what I would do for now too.

Comment: Why don't the dates match in the test column to the first column?  Yes it is now of date type but the days and months don't match. Is there a reason?

Comment: test gives out incorrect values for date. This is not the right answer.

Comment: Any solution with UDF is not an answer, barely a workaround. I dont think, there is many use cases that you cant do by combining PSF and .transform() itself.

Answer (score 36):

The strptime() approach does not work for me. I get another cleaner solution, using cast:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
spark_df1 = spark_df.withColumn("record_date",spark_df['order_submitted_date'].cast(DateType()))
#below is the result
spark_df1.select('order_submitted_date','record_date').show(10,False)

+---------------------+-----------+
|order_submitted_date |record_date|
+---------------------+-----------+
|2015-08-19 12:54:16.0|2015-08-19 |
|2016-04-14 13:55:50.0|2016-04-14 |
|2013-10-11 18:23:36.0|2013-10-11 |
|2015-08-19 20:18:55.0|2015-08-19 |
|2015-08-20 12:07:40.0|2015-08-20 |
|2013-10-11 21:24:12.0|2013-10-11 |
|2013-10-11 23:29:28.0|2013-10-11 |
|2015-08-20 16:59:35.0|2015-08-20 |
|2015-08-20 17:32:03.0|2015-08-20 |
|2016-04-13 16:56:21.0|2016-04-13 |
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked for me!
In case someone wants to convert a string like `2008-08-01T14:45:37Z` to a timestamp instead of date, `df = df.withColumn("CreationDate",df['CreationDate'].cast(TimestampType()))` works well... (Spark 2.2.0)

Comment: I tried this option among many from AWS Glue pyspark, works like charm!

Comment: This works if the date is already in an acceptable format (yyyy-MM-dd). In OP's case, the date's in MM-dd-yyyy format would return `null` using this method.

Answer (score 19):

In the accepted answer's update you don't see the example for the `to_date` function, so another solution using it would be:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    'new_date',
    F.to_date(
        F.unix_timestamp(
            'STRINGCOLUMN',
            'MM-dd-yyyy'
        ).cast('timestamp')
    )
)
```

Comment: doing a simple to_date() does not work, this is the correct answer

Comment: simply, `to_date('STRINGCOLUMN', 'MM-dd-yyyy')` should work. it accepts the source format.

Answer (score 13):

possibly not so many answers so thinking to share my code which can help someone

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example")\
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()


df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-06-22',)], ['t'])
df1 = df.select(to_date(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('dt'))
print df1
print df1.show()
```

output

```
DataFrame[dt: date]
+----------+
|        dt|
+----------+
|2019-06-22|
+----------+
```

the above code to convert to date if you want to convert datetime then use to_timestamp.
let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2018-07-27 10:30:00',)], ['Date_col'])
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.Date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).alias('dt_col'))
df.show()
+-------------------+  
|           Date_col|  
+-------------------+  
|2018-07-27 10:30:00|  
+-------------------+
```

Comment: You might consider elaborating on how your answer improves upon what's already been provided and accepted.