# pyspark dataframe : TypeError : to_date() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, to-date

Can someone help to resolve below issue :

I am trying to convert the string to date format in pyspark

```
datadf1 = datadf1.withColumn('vehicle_last_service_date_temp', to_date(datadf1.vehicle_last_service_date,"mm/dd/yyyy"))

TypeError: to_date() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: Suresh, the same code is working in pyspark console but it is breaking when i am running at aws glue console for pyspark

Comment: what's the error you get

Comment: TypeError: to_date() takes exactly 1 argument(2 given)

Comment: Can you give an example of date string that you have?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the above mention problem by using `unix_timestamp`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

datadf1 = datadf1.withColumn("vehicle_last_service_date_temp", 
                             F.date_format(F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp(datadf1.vehicle_last_service_date, "mm/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

As far as AWS glue issue for TypeError : `to_date()` takes exactly 1 argument (2 given).

There is must `pyspark` version issue, which glue is calling at the back end