# Passing date as parameter in Pyspark (Date is being converted into Integer when passed as argument)

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am passing date as parameter in a script.

```
"process_date":"2018-06-10"
```

And then trying to print this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys
process_date=datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%Y-%m-%d')
print(process_date)
```

But I am getting an error

```
time data '41685' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

The date parameter is getting converted to integer. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: No.Its different

Comment: how the python file is called in the script..?

Comment: I am trying to pass it to a notebook.

Comment: creating a databricks job which reads it as date

Comment: @BitanshuDas what is the expected output?

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(sys.argv[1])` before the call to `strptime`? How do you know the correct value is being passed in?

Comment: print(sys.argv[1]) gives me 39337