# How to convert a Unicode date / time string to python datetime in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

My question is about how to convert a Unicode date / time string to python datetime in pyspark

I have written a machine learning program using pyspark in a Databricks / AWS environment.   All my code works well except when converting a `Unicode string (u’4/6/2017 13:25’) to python datetime.`  I want to determine the difference in time between today and the purchase date.

My code is:

```
historicalE = historicalD.withColumn('new_purchase_date', f.date_format(historicalD.purchase_date.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType()), "%m-%d-%YT%H:%MZ"))
```

After running the code, the `“new_purchase_date” = None`

In another attempt, I tried:

```
historicalE = historicalD.withColumn('new_purchase_date', datetime.datetime.strptime(historicalD.purchase_date, '%m-%d-%YT%H:%M'))
```

This caused an interrupt `must be a string, not a column`

I have worked on this problem using several solutions for a day and am not making any progress.
Your suggestions are very appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: is it enough just `purchase_date.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType())`? The reason you are receving `None` as a result is because there is a Date format mismatching with the one that you provided. The only cast should be enough and a more relaxed condition, let me know if you still have `None` ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I continue to get "None" using the following code:

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately, I am still getting none after using your suggested change.  Also, for some reason, the purchase date is now a string vs. unicode string.  The current format is: purchase_date='4/6/2017 13:25'. I ran your code with no format and tried with several modified formats but I continue to get None.  All suggestions are welcome.