# PySpark: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have DataFrame in PySpark that has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I want to add one more column `date_time` of the type `timestamp`:

```
import datetime

to_datetime_func =  udf (lambda d, t: datetime.strptime(d+" "+t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), TimestampType())
df = df.withColumn("date_time", to_datetime_func("date","time"))
```

This code compiles well. However, when I run a simple filteroperation that uses `date_time` column, I get the error:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)


from pyspark.sql import functions as func

df \
    .filter(func.col("date_time")>=func.col("start"))
    .select("id","date_time","start") \
    .show()
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2966.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 765, 10.139.64.4, executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 403, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 398, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 365, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 147, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 354, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: toInternal(f(*a))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-4293391875175815>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:638)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2076)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:223)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
my_concat_func =  udf (lambda d, t: datetime.strptime(d+" "+t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), StringType())
df = df.withColumn("date", df["date"].cast(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("date_time", my_concat_func("date","time"))


df.select("date","time","date_time").printSchema()

root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_time: string (nullable = true)


df.select("date","time","date_time").show()
```

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:  03:34:26

Comment: you are trying to concat a datetime with a string, convert both to string and that should do

Comment: @IWHKYB: I tried it. Now both `date` and `time` are string values. Then I run my code to get `date_time` and then I run the rest of code and get the error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  01:08:29`.

Comment: Why are you using a `udf`? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: @pault: Because initially I have 2 separate columns: `date` and `time`. I should concatenate them in order to get `date_time`. Also, `date` is given in the format `2017-12-04 00:00:00`. I should drop ` 00:00:00` from every `date` value before concatenating. Therefore I created UDF.

Comment: All of those operations can be done using the API functions. Using a udf here is wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this and let me know the output :

```
timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    df \
        .filter((func.unix_timestamp('date_time', format=timeFmt) >= func.unix_timestamp('start', format=timeFmt)))
        .select("id","date_time","start") \
        .show()
```

**EDIT**

> For the question how to get only date and not time :

```
df = df.withColumn("new_data", func.to_date(df.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df.printSchema()

df = df.withColumn("new_data", df['new_data'].cast(StringType()))
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()

#### Output ####
+------------------------+
|date                    |
+------------------------+
|2015-07-02T11:22:21.050Z|
|2016-03-20T21:00:00.000Z|
+------------------------+
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_data: date (nullable = true)
+------------------------+----------+
|date                    |new_data  |
+------------------------+----------+
|2015-07-02T11:22:21.050Z|2015-07-02|
|2016-03-20T21:00:00.000Z|2016-03-20|
+------------------------+----------+
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_data: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'` at the `filter` line.

Comment: But I get the error only when I materialize the DataFrame with `show()`.

Comment: That's because of lazy evaluation , i am working on emulating the same condition and let me come back to you once i am able to do it.

Comment: Once you concat and typecast the date & time can you do the show command , because that may help saying if that line is causing the error

Comment: I jsut noticed that `date` column has always the following format `2017-12-04 00:00:00`. Apparently, `00:00:00` should be dropped before concatenating with `time`. Maybe this is the reason? Do you know how to get a proper date substring from `2017-12-04 00:00:00`?

Comment: Thanks, but I think that something is missing in your code. Where do you use `time` column?