# how to make a datetime from a string

Tags: pyspark

I have two columns which are in `string` but need to be converted into a `datetime` or date and time.

```
- Column1: 20190828T121539.000000+0200
- Column2: 20190828T121539.000+0200
```

How can I do this?

I used:

`.withColumn('test', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Column1', 'yyyyMMddThhmmss'))`

but doesn't seem to work

---

I've solved it with this:

> to_timestamp(col('EventDateTime').substr(1,15), "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss")

The last part of the value was irrelevant so I could use a substr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: Your format is not the same as the actual structure of your datetimes. You have `yyyyMMddThhmmss.(something)`