# Convert string column(JAN 2018) to date column(01-01-2018) for pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, datetime, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to convert a string type column to date type column using udf functions as given below

Example input column value:
**JAN 2018**

Expected output value:
**01-01-2018**

**here is my code**

```
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

squared_udf = udf(lambda z: datetime.strptime(z,'%b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), DateType())

df = df.select('TIME PERIOD', squared_udf('TIME PERIOD'))
```

**Output of my code:**

***DataFrame[TIME PERIOD: string, (TIME PERIOD): date]***

But I'm expecting spark dataframe updated with TIME PERIOD column

Please suggest on the same.

Comment: use to_date() and date_format() functions: `df.selectExpr('date_format(to_date("JAN 2018", "MMM yyyy"),"MM-dd-yyyy")')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)