# Databricks: Python generate a array with date

Tags: python, databricks

Is it possible to generate an array with date format like the following 
datearray=["20190901","20190902"...…..,"20190930"]

I want to do if I input a date range, it will automatically generate . the array

using databricks python

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that Sreeram's answer uses  Pandas, which does not take advantage of Databricks capabilities.

Thus, I am suggesting a more Databricks native way of doing this:

```
spark.sql("SELECT sequence(to_date('2018-01-01'), to_date('2018-03-01'), interval 1 month) AS Date").show()
```

which returns a list like [2018-01-01,2018-02-01,2018-03-01] with column name Date.

You can then convert it using

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
```

[Source1](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) 
[source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `pandas` for this task like this,

```
start = '20190101'
end = '20190501'

[str(x).replace('-', '').split()[0] for x in pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(start), end=pd.Timestamp(end), freq='1D')]
```

Instead of giving an end date if you want to give number of days, you can see this,

```
start = '20190101'
days = 100

[str(x).replace('-', '').split()[0] for x in pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(start), end=pd.Timestamp(start) + pd.Timedelta(days=days), freq='1D')]
```

Comment: that's great and helpfule