# How to parse a string like 4/23/19 to a timestamp in pysark

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

I have some columns with dates from a source files that look like 4/23/19

The 4 being the month, the 23 being the day and the 19 being 2019

How do I convert this to a timestamp in pyspark?

So far

```
def ParseDateFromFormats(col, formats):
  return coalesce(*[to_timestamp(col, f) for f in formats])

df2 = df2.withColumn("_" + field.columnName, ParseDateFromFormats(df2[field.columnName], ["dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yy"]).cast(field.simpleTypeName))
```

There doesn't seem to be a date format that would work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code didn't work might be cause you reversed days and months.
This works:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

time_df = spark.createDataFrame([('4/23/19',)], ['dt'])
time_df.withColumn('proper_date', to_date('dt', 'MM/dd/yy')).show()
+-------+-----------+
|     dt|proper_date|
+-------+-----------+
|4/23/19| 2019-04-23|
+-------+-----------+
```