# Convert String of YYYYMMDD to Date of DD.MM.YYYY in pySpark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I have a requirement in deriving a value of date and calculate the End Of Month difference.
From source, i have a string column "a" of value YYYYMMDD.
But, in target the column has to map based on below condition:

```
EOM(to_date(a, "DD.MM.YYYY")) >= EOM(current_date)   #Output dateType is date type
```

I'm able to create the current_date value by importing datetime in python. But unable to convert the first part of code. Could you able to help in following code on how to acheive.

Comment: Can you include the code for the part that you got working?

Comment: Not yet, getting problem in converting dd.mm.yyyy format as this string is not able to convert to date type using to_date function in pyspark. Please provide your idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is more a python question than a Pyspark one.

In Python you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
strip_time = datetime.strptime("01.01.2020", '%d.%m.%Y').timetuple()
print strip_time
```

and get:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

You can also do:

```
from time import time
print strip_time > time()
```

and get

```
True
```

So in Pyspark, with a **RDD**, you can first **map** you values using "datetime.strptime()" then do a **filter** and compare to "time()"

If you are working with **DataFrames** you can look here: [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: Actually the problem is:
For example: 
    **now = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.01.2019", '%d.%m.%Y').timetuple() or
    now = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.01.2019", '%d.%m.%Y').time() or

    O/p: will be in following format as allways - 2020-01-01**

But, i need it in 01.01.2020

Comment: You need a string? Not a date? Then why not just do a split on the original string and join it in the way you want?