# How to convert yyyymmddhhmmss in PySpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to convert yyyymmddhhmmss in PySpark dataframe.

Example: 20180718093158 is my input and I want the result like 2018-07-18 09:31:58

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: Do the given solution doesn't help. My format of the input is 20180718093158  not like  2018/07/18 093158

Comment: what about this df = df.select(
    'your_input', 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('your_input', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')).alias('datetime')
)

Comment: No, it is also not working. I tried to string split and concatenation operations. But I'm looking for any kind of timestamp conversion.

Answer (score 0):

First, cast your "date" column to string and then apply to_timestamp() function with format "yyyyMMddHHmmSS" as the second argument, i.e.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = withColumn(
    "date", 
    F.to_timestamp(F.col("date").cast("string"), "yyyyMMddHHmmSS")
)
```