# convert date into desired format in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe like below and using pyspark 2.4

```
Name    doj
kevin   08/15/2013
George  06/21/2014

df.printSchema()
 -- Name (String)
 -- dob (String)
```

I would like to convert doj to YYYY-MM-DD format and make sure i need to convert the doj to Datetype instead of String using pyspark.Is there any specific function available ? I appreciate your response

Comment: Any attempts at using `date_format`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`to_date()`** function.

```
df.show()
#+------+----------+
#|  Name|       doj|
#+------+----------+
#| Kevin|08/15/2013|
#|George|06/21/2014|
#+------+----------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("doj",to_date(col("doj"),'MM/dd/yyyy')).show()
#+------+----------+
#|  Name|       doj|
#+------+----------+
#| Kevin|2013-08-15|
#|George|2014-06-21|
#+------+----------+
df.withColumn("doj",to_date(col("doj"),'MM/dd/yyyy')).printSchema()
#root
# |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- doj: date (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dateconv(x):
        if x == None:
            x = 'null'
            return x
        else:
            return x.strftime('%Y-%M-%D')
dateconv(doj)
```

Something similar in python, I did this

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format