# convert string type column to datetime in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, time, pyspark

I have a column `Time` in my spark df. It is a string type. I need to convert it to datetime format. I have tried the following:

```
data.select(unix_timestamp(data.Time, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').cast(TimestampType()).alias("timestamp"))

data.printSchema()
```

The output is:

```
root
 |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
```

If I save it in a new df, then I am losing all of my other columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: It does not, I have checked the resources before posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withColumn` instead of `select`

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([('1997/02/28 10:30:00',"test")], ['Time','Col_Test'])

df = data.withColumn("timestamp",unix_timestamp(data.Time, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').cast(TimestampType()))
```

Output :

```
>>> df.show()
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|               Time|Col_Test|          timestamp|
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|1997/02/28 10:30:00|    test|1997-02-28 10:30:00|
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+

>>> data.printSchema()
root
 |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_Test: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_Test: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: somehow when I ran the code and execute `.printSchema` I have Time listed as string still... ` |-- Time: string (nullable = true)`

Comment: @Chique_Code, on which dataframe are you running printSchema? Can i see your full code where you have done proper assignment?

Comment: @Chique_Code Added the printSchema statements for your understanding.