# How to change String column to Date-Time Format in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset which contains Multiple columns and rows.[image]

Currently, it's in String type [image]And, I wanted to convert to a date-time format for further task.

I tried this below code which returns null

```
df = df.withColumn('Date_Time',df['Date_Time'].cast(TimestampType()))
df.show()
```

I tried some of the solutions from here, but none of them is working all, in the end, returns me null.

[Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 3):

Since your date format is non-standard, you need to use `to_timestamp` and specify the corresponding format:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('Date_Time', F.to_timestamp('Date_Time', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'))
```

Comment: but why it's converted to this format "2019-11-01 17:00:00" when we selected dd/MM/yyyy  ? Is there any way to convert to specify Date format?

Comment: @MohitSharma if you want to specify the date format, you can use `F.date_format('Date_Time', 'dd/MM/yyyy')`, for example. Note that this will convert the column type to string type. Also note that timestamp types are internally stored as integers, and the format shown in `df.show()` does not represent how it is stored.

Comment: Okay got it. Is there any way I can get the results with this format such as dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss etc?

Comment: Sure, just use `df2.withColumn('Date_Time', F.date_format('Date_Time', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'))`.  Note that you need to convert to timestamp type first, before you can use `date_format`. That's why I operated on `df2` in this comment.