# How to convert string to date in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a file name from which I'm extracting date: some_file_name_20201103114823.csv using `substring`:

`substring(input_file_name(),16,8)`

I extracted date part, which is now string: `20201103`

How can I convert this string to date in format: `MM-dd-yyyy` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score -1):

This is what i did, formatted string and then cast it to date - not pretty but does the work:

`to_date(concat(substring(input_file_name(),16,4),lit("-"),substring(input_file_name(),20,2),lit("-"),substring(input_file_name(),22,2)),"yyyy-MM-dd")`

Reference: [https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-substring-from-a-column/#:~:text=In%20PySpark%2C%20the%20substring(),using%20substring()%20from%20pyspark](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-substring-from-a-column/#:%7E:text=In%20PySpark%2C%20the%20substring(),using%20substring()%20from%20pyspark).