# Change datatype of a column in pyspark

Tags: python, oracle, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I have a column which has a date in the format of `MM/dd/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM`. But currently the format is in string type. While loading this data into Oracle table, it is giving me `type conversion error` from String to Date type.

I tried `to_date()` `and date_format()` functions in pyspark but `to_date()` is truncating my value to only date `MM/dd/YYYY` and `date_format()` is keeping it in string only.

Is there any way i change the datatype of my column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_timestamp` function to convert the string to timestamp format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [('01/07/2022 10:12:00 AM',),], schema = ['ts_as_str'])

#to_timestamp function converts to specified format of timestamp, as in 2nd argument.
df_1 = df.select(to_timestamp(df.ts_as_str, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a').alias('ts_as_ts'))

df_1.printSchema()
display(df_1)
```

[image: Converted column as timestamp]

Load the converted dataframe to oracle.
Oracle or another RDBMS has its own way of handling date. So, the format you see in oracle could be different from this one.