# Converting String to dates in pyspark

Tags: python, date, pyspark

I have a String in the format of "MMM-YY" (ie) "jun-22","Jan-22" etc.
I want to convert it into Date with 01st Day of Month in the following format.

```
Jan-22 --> 01-Jan-22
Feb-21 --> 01-Feb-21
```

I have tried a few ways but couldn't get to the solution.
Can someone please advise on what is the quickest and most efficient way of doing this in a Pyspark Dataframe.

Code used could be pyspark or Python.

Comment: lowercase `y` for year in pyspark -- see [available patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). also share what you've tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that, so just tried converting using from_unixtime, but that didn't work

Comment: If it's a string, why can't you just prepend '01-' ?

Comment: If  stuck, this may get you out of the hook `spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Jan-22","11/24/1991","11/30/1991"), 
                            ("Feb-21","11/24/1992","11/30/1992")], schema=['first', 'second', 'third'])
df1.show()

new = (df1.withColumn('first',split(col('first'),'-'))#Split string by '-' to create list
       .withColumn('first',concat_ws('-',lit('01'),*[col("first")[i] for i in range(2)]))#create string date
.withColumn('date_desired',F.expr(" to_date(first ,'dd-MMMM-yy') "))#coerce to date
      )`

Comment: Hi, you should include examples of what you've already tried and how didn't it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I was able to add "01-" at the beginning of the date string and converting it into a date.